# Mocking timers in pRetry function for testing purpose

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'd like to test a function which uses [pRetry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-retry) npm package with Jest testing framework. I want to speed up tests flow, thus I don't want to wait until pRetry actual timers trigger. To simplify the task, I'd like to have my test run less than 500 ms, and console.log message in // *** line is printed 7 (or 8?) times.
I've tried using jest.useFakeTimers, jest.runAllTimers and [others](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestusefaketimersimplementation-modern--legacy) with no success.
Please, help, I stuck :)

my function looks like:

```
myFunc() {
  return pRetry(async () => {
    if(Math.random() > 0.5){
      return true;
    }

    console.log(`currentTime: ${Date.now()}`); // ***

    throw new Error('Calculations failed....');
  }, {
    retries: 7,
    minTimeout: 500,
  });
}
```

my test looks like:

```
 it('should throw an error if calculations failed', async () => {
      await myFunc();

      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Needed this but could not find a way neither.

I ended up making the minTimeout of pRetry get its value from a function which I stub during testing (and so I export)

something like that:

```
// used to be overwritten by testing
export const getMinTimeout = () => 1000;
```

```
  await pRetry(
    async () => {
      return doRetry();
    },
    {
      minTimeout: exports.getMinTimeout(),
     
    }
```

```
      sandbox.stub(ApiV2, 'getMinTimeout').returns(10);
```

this works well

Answer (score 1):

I managed to (very simply) mock p-retry using Jest :

```js
jest.mock('p-retry', () => async (fn) => {
  const tryFn = async (attemptCount) => {
    try {
      return await fn(attemptCount)
    } catch (error) {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1))
      return tryFn(attemptCount + 1)
    }
  }

  return tryFn(0)
})
```